# Подсчет динамических полей во Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть поля формы, которые создаются динамически. Нужно расчитать 5 поле()Стоимость по формуле: width * len * height. Только я не могу понять, как это все правильно сделать. Проблема заключается с получением данных. У  watch я получаю только тот input который изменяю, а нужно получить и остальные.

```
 <template id="baggage-template">
        <div>

            <div class="row" v-for="(input, index) in inputs">

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="control-label">Ширина</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="input.width"  placeholder="см">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Длина</label>
                        <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.len" placeholder="см">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Высота</label>
                        <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.height" placeholder="см">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" >
                    <label class="control-label">Вес</label>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.weight" placeholder="кг">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="control-label">Стоимость</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"  v-model="input.price" name="input.baggage_price">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" title="Удалить"  @click="deleteRow(index)">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" @click="addRow">Добавить место багажа</button>
        </div>
    </template>

  Vue.component('baggage', {
        template:'#baggage-template',
        data: function(){
          return {
              checked:false,
              inputs: []
          }
        },
        props:['id','title', 'price'],
        methods:{
            addRow:function() {
                this.inputs.push({
                    width: '',
                    len: '',
                    height: '',
                    weight: '',
                    price:4,
                })
            },

            deleteRow(index) {
                this.inputs.splice(index,1)
            },

        },

        watch: {
            'inputs.0.width': {
                handler: function (val, oldVal) {
                   //здесь делать расчет вида: width * len * height
                }
            },
            'inputs.0.len': {
                handler: function (val, oldVal) {

                }
            },
            'inputs.0.height': {
                handler: function (val, oldVal) {

                }
            },
            'inputs.0.weight': {
                handler: function (val, oldVal) {

                }
            }

        }


    });
```

Визуальный вид формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоимость только рассчитывается или может быть вручную изменена?

Comment: только рассчитывается. Нужно будет просто сделать input disabled

Comment: тогда проще всего сделать это поле свойством самого объекта `input`, а не частью `vue`, особенно, если потом ты хочешь его на сервер слать, а не просто отображать

Comment: Да на сервер нужно слать будет, только без ajax.

Comment: Уже понятнее. А почему без ajax? через просто `submit` у формы?

Comment: да через submit. Суть следующая: есть страница оформления билета(ов). Там заполняем данные каждого пассажира. Также для каждого пассажира можно указать к-во мест для багажа. К примеру может быть так: 3 пасажира (билета). 1 пассажир указано 3 багажа, 2-й указан один багаж, 3-й 0.

Comment: Учитывая: ширину, высоту, длину и вес, рассчитывается стоимость провоза багажа. Сверху добавил картинку для понимания.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так: 
`<input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="input.width"  placeholder="см" @input="setPrice(input)">`
аналогично по полям длины и высоты.
и в секции methods:

```
setPrice(input) {
  const {width, length, height} = input;
  const price = (!width || !length || !height) ? null : width*length*height;
  this.$set(input, 'price', price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант добавить обработчик на изменение поля и в нем делать расчет:

```
        <div class="row" v-for="(input, index) in inputs">

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label">Ширина</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="input.width" @input="handler(index)"  placeholder="см">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Длина</label>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.len" @input="handler(index)" placeholder="см">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Высота</label>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.height" @input="handler(index)" placeholder="см">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" >
                <label class="control-label">Вес</label>
                <input class="form-control"  type="text" v-model="input.weight" @input="handler(index)" placeholder="кг">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label">Стоимость</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  v-model="input.price" name="input.baggage_price">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" title="Удалить"  @click="deleteRow(index)">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" @click="addRow">Добавить место багажа</button>
    </div>
</template>

  Vue.component('baggage', {
        template:'#baggage-template',
        data: function(){
          return {
              checked:false,
              inputs: []
          }
        },
        props:['id','title', 'price'],
        methods:{
            addRow:function() {
                this.inputs.push({
                    width: '',
                    len: '',
                    height: '',
                    weight: '',
                    price:4,
                })
            },

            deleteRow(index) {
                this.inputs.splice(index,1)
            },

            handler(index) {
              let {height, width, len} = this.inputs[index]
              this.inputs[index].price = height * width * len
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Возникла еще проблема. Как принять данные динамических полей на стороне сервера. Мне нужно как то получить post массив вида:
baggage[one][0] = 22; baggage[one][1] = 22, baggage[one][2] = 22,
baggage[two][0] = 0, baggage[two][1] = 22.

Comment: В итоге, я получаю один сплошной массив. Данный компонент может вызыватся не один раз. Так как это страница у меня оформления билета, а билетов может быть и не один.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал не много по другому. Через computed, само значения скрываю на выводе:

```
 <span style="visibility: hidden">@{{calc}}</span>


    Vue.component('baggage', {
        template:'#baggage-template',
        data: function(){
          return {
              checked:false,
              hide:false,
              inputs: []
          }
        },
        props:['id','title', 'price'],
        methods:{
            addRow:function() {
                this.inputs.push({
                    width: '',
                    len: '',
                    height: '',
                    weight: '',
                    suma:'',
                })
            },

            deleteRow(index) {
                this.inputs.splice(index,1)
            },

            calc(width, len, height, weight){
                vol = (width * len * height) / 5000
                if(vol > 9.6 || weight > 20){
                    return this.price / 2;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        },

       computed:{
           totalPrice() {
               return this.inputs.reduce((total, item) => {
                   return item.suma = this.calc(item.width, item.len, item.height, item.weight);
               }, 0);
           }
       },



    });
```

Comment: У тебя неверно написано в разметке `{{calc}}`. `calc` — это не `computed property`, а **метод**. Поэтому смысла в выводе `<span style="visibility: hidden">@{{calc}}</span>` вообще нет.

Comment: Если убрать @{{calc}}, то в поле input нечего менятся не будет.

Comment: В приведенном коде, не видно где вообще поле `price`, судя по всему оно заменено на `suma`, но даже в это случае, оно меняется в странном месте, и `totalPrice` делает не то и не так.

Comment: все верно заменено поле price на suma. Правил просто.